# Use Jquery to remove first URL in a double URL link

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink

I am trying to remove the first url in a double url link such as:

http://somewebsite.com/something/#/###/#/http://someotherwebsite.com/

after a page loads. So afterwards, would look something like:

http://someotherwebsite.com/

Where # = numbers

Sometimes the first website is a .org or.net. I tried searching and tried ideas but never remove the first full link.

Comment: ***Why*** are there two URLs there? It's not meaningful. Could you store the second URL in a `data-` attribute instead of the `src` attribute?

Comment: Can't that be separated by `,` ?

Comment: Are you trying to remove it in the browser's address bar? or just a link on the page?

Comment: on a page, its a link you have to click to continue, basically an advertisement website link so you have to click see the ad then it redirects you to the second site, if the first url is removed then wouldn't have to see the ad.

Comment: I might add the second URL is dynamically generated, its not a constant same url as it links to other pages. So might be http://someotherwebsite.com/homeontherange or http://someotherwebsite.com/lets_play_ball or even numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not pretty, but this will get you at least on the correct track:

```
links = 'http://somewebsite.com/something/#/###/#/http://someotherwebsite.com/'
links = links.split('http')
console.log(links[2])
```

that will give you the second link (removing the 'http', but from there you can just add it back on and do what you need. It's not pretty, but it doesn't sound like you are looking for an elegant solution

If you want to know more about the split() function, it basically splits (hence the name) a string based on an input (the 'http' in our case). From there you can just traverse through it or do whatever you want with the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
str =  "http://" + (str.split('http://')[2]);
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Em9SU/

Answer (score 1):

Try to extract information with url regex:

```
var matches = tmp.match(/^(https?\:\/\/[^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eEffh/1/)